# Closed convex subsets of the Hilbert cube with positive measure

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $H={[-1,1]}^\omega$ be the classical Hilbert cube endowed with the Tychonoff topology and let $C\subseteq H$ be closed and convex. Let $\lambda$ be the usual product probability measure on $H$, i.e. the countable product of the uniform probability measures on $[-1,1]$. My question is: assuming that $\lambda(C)>0$, can I conclude that $C$ must contain a tiny copy of $H$? That is: can it be proved that there exist $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in H$ such that $x+\epsilon H\subseteq C$? This would be in analogy with what happens in finite-dimensional spaces: closed, convex subsets of ${[-1,1]}^n$ have zero Lebesgue measure if and only if they have empty interior, i.e. they do not contain any rescaled copy of ${[-1,1]}^n$. However, when it comes to dealing with infinite dimensions I am stucked. If you have comments or suggestions, that would be much appreciated.

Edit: it is important to notice that the interior of $C$ can be empty: the product
\begin{equation}
C=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\biggl[-1,1-\frac{1}{n^2}\biggr]
\end{equation}
is convex, closed and has empty interior, but by the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n^{-2}$ and some basic theory on infinite products one can conclude that $\lambda(C)>0$. However, it is clear that $C$ does not work as a counterexample, as it contains a copy of $1/2\cdot H$.